# Migration of PaaS Services from ASM to ARM

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

This may be a dummy question but what are the typical steps needed to migrate PaaS Services (Redis, SQL Azure) from ASM to ARM (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

In short you need to duplicate / span your services across the two (ASM and ARM) and then decommission the ASM resources.

For SQL Server, use Always On replication to span over to ARM instances and then decommission your ASM instances. I have not migrated Redis but I assume the same patter will apply (or using two separate Redis instances, one in each). If your data is not particularly huge and you can afford some down time, then you could easily do this overnight.

Also look at [MigAz](https://github.com/Azure/migAz) - it is target at IAAS (I know you asked about PAASm but it is still a useful resource). This tool allows you to define how your ASM resources should look in ARM (in terms of resource groups, network con]figuration, etc). The tool helps with producing ARM templates for your ASM resources.

Keep in mind that if you remain within an Azure data center you get the advantage of the local network connectivity performance and no ingress/egress cost.

Comment: Thanks.Not clear on how AlwaysOn will work with SQL Azure..Any info on how to cater for Redis Migration?

Comment: Add  second Redis instance in your ASM. Modify your producer app to write to both instances, once populated modify the consumer to read from the new instance, then decommission the old.